# Não consigo utilizar a classe R. no kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estou tentando aprender *kotlin* , mas não estou conseguindo importar a classe "R." no kotlin.
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Alguém saberia me informar o que estou fazendo de errado ?**

Comment: Build -> rebuild

Comment: Tive um erro parecido ao seu, conetei-me a internet, e atualizei o Gradle tasks, deia duplo clique no linki abaixo do erro.

Comment: Esse erro costuma ocorrer quando vc tem algum erro no xml do seu layout

Answer (score 1):

Isso aconteceu comigo também, eu fiz Build->Clean Project e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

"R" não é uma classe, mas sim resources (a sua pasta res da aplicação)

Tente remover o "R" de com.claudioshigemi.carros.activity.**R**

Comment: R é uma classe sim, e ela é gerada dinamicamente quando ocorrer um build do projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar ir no menu Build e no submenu Clean Project ou Reiniciar o Android Studio. Em alguns casos apenas reiniciando volta ao normal. O Android Studio às vezes tem esses bugs de não reconhecer alguma classe.